# Sql Server Rank on Value Range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with three columns, ID, Date, Value.  I want to rank the rows such that, within an ID, the Ranking goes up with each date where Value is at least X, otherwise, Ranking stays the same.

Given ID, Date, and Values like these

```
1, 6/1, 8
1, 6/2, 12
1, 6/3, 14
1, 6/4, 9
1, 6/5, 11
```

I would like to return a ranking based on values of at least 10, such that I would have ID, Date, Value, and Rank like this:

```
1, 6/1, 8, 0
1, 6/2, 12, 1
1, 6/3, 14, 2
1, 6/4, 9, 2
1, 6/5, 11, 3
```

In other words, the ranking increases each time the value exceeds a threshhold, otherwise it stays the same.

What I have tried is

```
SELECT T1.*, X.Ranking FROM TABLE T1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *, DENSE_RANK( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY T2.ID ORDER BY T2.DATE ) Ranking
    FROM TABLE T2 WHERE T2.VALUE >= 10 ) X
ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.Date = T2.Date
```

This almost works.  It gets me output like

```
1, 6/1, 8, NULL
1, 6/2, 12, 1
1, 6/3, 14, 2
1, 6/4, 9, NULL
1, 6/5, 11, 3
```

Then, I want to turn the first NULL into a 0, and the second into a 2.

I turned the above query into a cte and tried

```
    SELECT T1.*, CASE WHEN T1.Ranking IS NULL THEN ISNULL( (
        SELECT MAX( T2.Ranking ) 
        FROM cte T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.Date > T2.Date, 0 ) 
            ELSE T1.Ranking END NewRanking
    FROM cte T1
```

This looks like it would work, but my table has 200,000 rows and the query ran for 25 minutes...  So, I'm looking for something a little more out of the box than the SELECT MAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using SQL Server 2012, so you can do a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when value >= 10 then 1 else 0 end) over
              (partition by id order by date) as ranking
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This actually does not work. In spirit it fetches the previous LAG value and increment it, but this is not how LAG works... it would be 'recursive' in essence which results in a 'my_rank' is undefined syntax error. Better solution is the accepted answer based on a cumulative sum.

<strike>If you have SQL Server 2012 (you didn't tag your question), you can do something like:</strike>

```
SELECT 
  LAG(my_rank, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) 
  + CASE WHEN VALUE >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_rank
FROM T1
```

Comment: I am looking at this.  My initial problem with LAG is in setting the offset; if I have two or more low-value rows in a row, offset of 1 is only going to work on the first one.

Comment: Not sure about what the problem is precisely. If you had the same `PARTITION BY id` I think you should get the same result as Gordon's query.

Comment: The difference comes when there are two below-10 values in a row.  The LAG approach correctly sees the first one and sets my_rank to the value from the previous row, but when it sees the second one, it again sets my_rank to the value from the previous row, but at this time that value is still the original value, not the fix applied to the result set, so it still sets it to zero.

Comment: I've tried inside SQL Server and I see the problem. My solution is not correct because as it is defined it would be a kind of recursive query (you get an error: my_rank is undefined). Trying to fix it with LAG is indeed pointless because it doesn't work that way (LAG doesn't fetch the result of itself on the previous row). That could be done with a CTE but probably quite inefficiently. I'm editing my answer to point out it's incorrect.